# Basic HTTP Authentication from Salesforce to Taleo

Tags: http, authentication, soap, apex-code, taleo

I am a newbie and am writing a SOAP web service (for integration purpose), in order to execute the SOAP call I need to authenticate the user first(standard integration user).

Following is the code snippet for it. However, when I execute the callout, it throws error code 500 for Basic Http request and error code 401 for the second Http request.

Is this the correct approach?

```
HTTP auth = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest r = new HTTPRequest();
r.setEndpoint('https://domainname.net/enterprise/soap?ServiceName=IntegrationManagementService');
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username+':'+password);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
r.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
r.setMethod('POST');

try
{
 HTTPResponse authresp = auth.send(r);
 if(authresp.getStatusCode() == 200)
       { 
           system.debug('Authentication success!!!' + authresp);
       }
       else
       {system.debug('Authentication failed!!!' + authresp + authresp.getStatusCode());}    
         }catch(exception e){}

   //construct http request
    string endpointURL = 'https://doaminname.net/enterprise/soap?ServiceName=IntegrationManagementService';
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setMethod('POST');

   req.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
   req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/xml');
   req.setBody(TaleoXML);

   //send http request
   Http http = new Http();
   try
   {
       HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

       //check the response
       if(res.getStatusCode() == 200)
       { 
           system.debug('Callout success!!!' + res);
       }
       else
       {system.debug('Callout failed!!!' + res + res.getStatusCode());}    
   }catch(exception e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the library you're using here, but I can suggest a few possibilities to investigate:

- Basic authentication is a stateless method. You don't log in and stay logged in with it. This means there's no separate initial authentication request (as your code implies); you include the `Authorization` header with every request. That's why you're getting the [401](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) on the second request.
- On the first request, you are providing credentials and the the server is encountering an unexpected internal error (that's what [500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) means). If it includes a body with the error response, it might have more information. I would guess that it has something to do with the fact that you didn't provide a body with your POST and the server was not expecting that.

If this is the first time you're using SOAP, you would probably be better off using a dedicated SOAP library rather than trying to construct requests yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the second request you don't include Authentication, that's why you get a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

In the first request, it seems you authenticate ok but the server fails to process the request. I think you missed to refer to the function/operation of the IntegrationManagementService webservice that you want to use. Or you are using a function/operation that needs MTOM enabled.